# Creating an instance of a superclass and feed its values to it's child classes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have created a class that takes in a few variables for an api (key, region). I have created after other classes that extend said class and utilize the data from the superclass to access the api endpoints. I defined the classes like this:

```
class api {
    constructor(key, region, username){
        this.key = key;
        this.region = region;
        this.username = username;
    }
}
class endpoint extends api {
    constructor(){
   super(key,region,username)
}
}
```

My question is if, when calling these classes, if I can define the superclass, and not having to insert its variables, as in:

```
const api = new api(key, region, username);
const endpoint = new endpoint;
endpoint.someSubEndpoint();
```

Because when I defined the subclasses, the constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(){
   super(key,region,username)
}
```

And to me it seems that I must feed the paramaters to every object I create, when I want to feed it once to the superclass at the beggining.

Comment: which one is the superclass and please show us how you're extending this class. The question is not clear at the moment

Comment: ah ok. It's simple: you don't need to instance the api class. build directly the endpoint class. If you want to create multiple endpoints that share the same data: save the properties as class properties instead of object properties.

Comment: Hey, I'm still a noob in JavaScript and this is one of my projects in OOP js, so if you dont mind me asking, how do I save the properties as class properties? I'm assuming what I did with my code was saving them as object preoperties.

Comment: Class properties are like `api.prop = value` instead of `this.prop = value`